# Java8: How to Convert Map<X, List<Y>> to Map<Y,X> using Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java8. A problem that I want to solve is to convert Map> to Map using Stream. For example:

```
input: {A => [B, C, D], E => [F]}
output: {B => A, C => A, D => A, F => E}
```

Let's assume that there is no duplicated value in List. How to do it in java 8 stream in an elegant way?

Cheers,
Wei

Comment: Is a stream a *must*?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jim, I tried the exact same approach that user149547 gives. However, my eclipse Luna refuse to do the correct type reference, which made me think that I was wrong.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: what else do you suggest? I just want to find a simple and readable way to do the work.

Comment: I was going give what Jim Garrison gave in the second part since it's the cleanest IMHO.

Comment: Thanks. I will go with the cleanest ways. Thank everyone for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer,String>        pam = new HashMap<>();
```

This will do what you want

```
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream().forEach(v -> pam.put(v, e.getKey())));
```

This takes advantage of the fact that `Set<E>` implements `stream()` from `Collection`. The rest is just plugging things into the right place.

Or, as suggested by @user140547 (thank you), an even simpler solution

```
    map.forEach((k,v) -> v.forEach(vv -> pam.put(vv, k)));
```

Comment: Among all the above approach, which one do you recommend.

Comment: @liuwei7923 The second one.  It is the most succinct and idiomatic. Also, you should upgrade to the latest Eclipse (Neon).  It is quite possible older versions have bugs in compiling lambda expressions.  You are TWO major releases behind.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a solution without `forEach()` you can do:

```
    Map<Integer, String> pam = 
            map.entrySet().stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.getValue().stream().map(v -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(v, x.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

For each Entry like `"3"-> [3,4,5,6]` a Stream of Entries like `3->3,4->3,5->3,6->3` is created, using `flatMap` it can be flattened to one stream, then `Collectors.toMap()` creates the final `Map`.

Comment: I tried the exact same approach. And eclipse shows me a compile error, which is "The type Map.Entry does not define getKey(Object) that is applicable here". After reading your answer, I researched a bit on google and found out that it is a know issue with Luna, detail in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091946/java-8-stream-flatmap-and-group-by-code-compiler-error. After upgrade to Mars, everything just worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's really reasy using the free [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library written by me:

```
EntryStream.of(map).invert().flatMapKeys(Collection::stream).toMap();
```

Here [`EntryStream.of(map)`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#of-java.util.Map-) creates a stream of map entries which is extended by additional operations; [`invert()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#invert--) swaps keys and values, [`flatMapKeys()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#flatMapKeys-java.util.function.Function-) flattens keys leaving values unchanged and [`toMap()`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/EntryStream.html#toMap--) collects the resulting entries back to map.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @JimGarrison Using [Map.forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) it is much easier

```
input.forEach( (key,value)-> value.forEach(vvalue -> output.put(vvalue, key)));
```